# joining two data frames together based on a data condition

Tags: r

I am trying to join these two data frames together based on some date condition.

I have monthly Price/sales data in `d1` and I want to join it with `d2`. `d2` is annual data and `d1` is monthly data.

I want to join them together such that I take the `date2` in `d2` and join it with `date1` in `d1` by the first observable month in `d1`.

That is `d1:date1` has to be greater tan `d2:date2`. I want to join by `ID` and `date2` in `d2` with the first available month date `date1` in `d1`.

I hope this makes sence.

I like doing things in the tidyverse as I find it simple to understand but I have run into memory issues in the past so a data.table version would be awesome.

There are some duplicates in the data so perhaps using `... %>% distinct(., .keep_all = TRUE)` might filter some of these out.

d1 - time series monthly data

```
        ID      date1   prc
1 69331C10 2012-01-31 40.66
2 69331C10 2012-02-29 41.68
3 69331C10 2012-03-30 43.41
4 69331C10 2012-04-30 44.18
5 69331C10 2012-05-31 43.70
6 69331C10 2012-06-29 45.27
```

d2 -

```
        ID      date2 var1
1 09179710 2012-02-24    1
2 74979E10 2012-02-23    1
3 98252610 2012-02-24    1
4 89190610 2012-02-28    1
5 83418210 2012-02-23    1
6 71694110 2012-07-16    1

d1 <- structure(list(ID = c("69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", 
"69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", 
"69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", 
"69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", "69331C10", 
"69331C10", "69331C10", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", 
"43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", 
"43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", 
"43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", "43258910", 
"43258910", "43258910", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", 
"89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", 
"89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", 
"89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", "89190610", 
"89190610", "89190610"), date1 = structure(c(15370, 15399, 15429, 
15460, 15491, 15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 15674, 15705, 
15736, 15764, 15792, 15825, 15856, 15884, 15917, 15947, 15978, 
16009, 16038, 16070, 15370, 15399, 15429, 15460, 15491, 15520, 
15552, 15583, 15611, 15644, 15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 15792, 
15825, 15856, 15884, 15917, 15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070, 
15370, 15399, 15429, 15460, 15491, 15520, 15552, 15583, 15611, 
15644, 15674, 15705, 15736, 15764, 15792, 15825, 15856, 15884, 
15917, 15947, 15978, 16009, 16038, 16070), class = "Date"), prc = c(40.6599998474121, 
41.6800003051758, 43.4099998474121, 44.1800003051758, 43.7000007629395, 
45.2700004577637, 46.1599998474121, 43.4099998474121, 42.6699981689453, 
42.5200004577637, 40.9500007629395, 40.1800003051758, 42.6399993896484, 
42.6399993896484, 44.5299987792969, 48.439998626709, 44.9099998474121, 
45.7299995422363, 45.8899993896484, 41.3600006103516, 40.9199981689453, 
41.8499984741211, 40.3699989318848, 40.2799987792969, 19.1499996185303, 
20.25, 21.5300006866455, 22.0400009155273, 20.8999996185303, 
28.9899997711182, 25.6100006103516, 26.0699996948242, 26.7800006866455, 
26.0100002288818, 27.8500003814697, 28.1399993896484, 30.9799995422363, 
32.4000015258789, 35.1500015258789, 35.9099998474121, 34.6399993896484, 
33.0800018310547, 35.2099990844727, 32.310001373291, 30.7399997711182, 
32.8300018310547, 33.4199981689453, 33.439998626709, 21.4400005340576, 
21.8799991607666, 23.0699996948242, 23.5200004577637, 23.2700004577637, 
23.9300003051758, 23.6499996185303, 23.1800003051758, 23.7000007629395, 
22.4899997711182, 21.9500007629395, 21.4200000762939, 23.25, 
23.7600002288818, 24.7800006866455, 23.6200008392334, 23.5100002288818, 
24.4799995422363, 27.4099998474121, 27.6700000762939, 29.4200000762939, 
29.8299999237061, 31.0499992370605, 33.2799987792969)), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = "data.frame")


d2 <- structure(list(ID = c("09179710", "74979E10", "98252610", "89190610", 
"83418210", "71694110", "70455110", "70455110", "69331C10", "43258910"
), date2 = c("2012-02-24", "2012-02-23", "2012-02-24", "2012-02-28", 
"2012-02-23", "2012-07-16", "2012-02-01", "2012-02-29", "2012-02-16", 
"2012-02-23"), var1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.999999957207671, 
0.999999957207671, 0.998543649717913, 0.986842264036935)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Do you need a non-equi join `library(data.table);setDT(d1)[d2, on = .(ID, date1 > date2)]`

Comment: I think. My `date2` was a character. So `d2$date2 <- as.Date(d2$date2)
d <- setDT(d1)[d2, on = .(ID, date1 > date2)]` - might work. I will inspect it further now

Comment: yes, I did change that, thought it was a typo from creating the example

Comment: In `d1` I have 72 observations and in `d2` I have 10 observations, when I join them together I have `76` observations.

Comment: it is due to dupes in both data for the joining columns.  At least one of the the dataset needs to have a unique joining column

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense

Comment: You may have to come up with a logic such that the joining column is unique in one dataset

Comment: One problem I am seeing with the `data.table` method is that `date1` gets "overwritten". That is in `d1` I have monthly observations `> head(d1$date1)
[1] "2012-01-31" "2012-02-29" "2012-03-30" "2012-04-30" "2012-05-31" "2012-06-29"` whereas now in `d` I have `> head(d$date1)
[1] "2012-02-24" "2012-02-23" "2012-02-24" "2012-02-28" "2012-02-28" "2012-02-28"`. For each `ID` I have the same date, whereas before it was monthly dates. The `prc` column remains correct.